# Using setTimeout with React.js before changing state

Tags: reactjs

I would like to use setTimeout with React.js before changing state in a function.  I would like to use it in the onHeaderTyped function.  I've tried including the TimerMixin but I received an error (it was undefined).  Any other routes?

```
Typing = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
      return { showFirst: true, showSecond: false, showThird: false };
  },

  onHeaderTyped: function() {
      this.setState({showFirst: false});
      this.setState({showSecond: true});
  },

  onSecondTyped: function() {
      this.setState({showSecond: false});
      this.setState({showThird: true});

  },

  onThirdTyped: function() {
    this.setState({showThird: false});
    this.setState({showFirst: true});

  },

  render: function() {
    const docs = '#one';
    return (



<div>
      <div className="TypistExample">

        {this.state.showFirst ? (

        <Typist className="TypistExample-header" avgTypingSpeed={100} startDelay={1000}
          onTypingDone={this.onHeaderTyped} cursor={{hideWhenDone: true}}>
          <h1><a href={docs}>First Stuff</a></h1>
        </Typist>

        ) : null }

        {this.state.showSecond ? (

        <Typist className="TypistExample-header" avgTypingSpeed={100} startDelay={1000} 
          onTypingDone={this.onSecondTyped}>
          <h1> Some Stuff </h1>
        </Typist>

        ) : null }

        {this.state.showThird ? (

        <Typist className="TypistExample-header" avgTypingSpeed={100} startDelay={1000} 
          onTypingDone={this.onThirdTyped}>
          <h1> More Stuff </h1>
        </Typist>

        ) : null }


      </div>
</div>

    );
  }

});
```

As an aside, while running this, I am getting this error:

Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the undefined component.

Comment: Where are you trying to use the setTimeout? PS no need to call setState twice - `this.setState({showThird: false, showFirst: true});`

Comment: code is a mess but  i see you're passing a lot of your handlers without bindings. `onTypingDone={this.onHeaderTyped}` instead of `onTypingDone={() => this.onHeaderTyped()}` or `onTypingDone={this.onHeaderTyped.bind(this)}`.

Comment: how would I be able to clean this up?  I realize there must be a better way to have the text appear on the same line and switch between each other, but not sure how.

Comment: @naomik no need to bind if you're not passing any arguments *shrug*, may as well just send the reference down.

Comment: @user1072337 you can change your ternery statements to `{ condition && <div /> }`. if condition is false nothing will appear, you don't need `null`

Comment: @azium you couldn't be more wrong. binding changes the context of the function; or in this case, *retains* the context. Without binding, `this` will not reference the component instance and things like `this.setState` will be `undefined`. Function binding is actually less used for arguments than it is for attaching a function's intended context. That said, Function.prototype.bind is ugly and arrow functions, which preserve lexical this, are much preferred imo.

Comment: @naomik, would you mind letting me know how I can clean this up while maintaining the same functionality?

Comment: @naomik this is true if and only if you're using a `class`. The `React.createClass` method autobinds your functions. Also, when using a class that extends Component, you should bind your functions in the constructor, not render, so that you do not constantly rebind your functions. I could definitely be more wrong. Also--agreed on arrow functions--much nicer.

Comment: @user1072337 have you not tried simply using `setTimeout` in your function and calling `setState` inside the callback? `setTimeout(() => this.setState({ newValues }), ms)`

Comment: Also, can you post your `Typist` component? That warning is likely a race condition in one of your conditionally applied components attempting to call setState

Comment: @user1072337 provided an answer for you. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: @azium [magical auto-binding](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-autobinding) and mixins are on their way out as React matures and continues to support ES6. I never use bind because it's almost always unnecessary. Your recommendation of binding all of your functions sounds like you just don't understand how function contexts work in JavaScript. Also, search for "Function.prototype.bind is slow" on Google sometime, you might be a bit disheartened by what you find. If you have any questions, let me know. I'm happy to help you understand more.

Comment: @naomik I never said bind *all* your functions--this conversation started because you were addressing a lack of binding when in this particular case it wasn't necessary. I think your answer is good but should be written in the syntax of the question--OP never mentioned what they were using to transpile jsx.

Comment: @azium, fair, I overlooked OP was using `createClass`. I've actually ridded my mind of the old auto-binding behaviour and see this kind of function passing as a glaring mistake now. I should've paid closer attention. Regarding transpiling, OP is already using JSX and I can't say "use an arrow function" without also using ES6. So required transpiling is sort of implied with the use of arrow functions.